# Draw pictures with tikz on blogger

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

can I ask, how can I put the tikz code on blogger to get an image like the Tex side?

Comment: blogger doesn't run tex: the normal way would be as on this site, to take a screenshot of the tikz run on your local machine, and add it to the page as an image.

Comment: Theoretically this is possible in the following way : you create a server (like latex.ytotech.com or latexonline.cc) that receives the latex (tikz) code as url parameter and provides an image (png or svg). Then you can insert some image with url like this `<img href="myserver.org?latex=....">`. The bad news is that I don't think that this kind of server exists for now.

Comment: Another way is to convert dvi (or pdf) to svg via dvisvgm (included in all major distributions of TeX) and then include the svg code in the html code of the blog. svg is a vectorial format for images. A project for direct conversion of a Ti*k*Z picture in svg directly in the browser in [TikZJax](https://github.com/kisonecat/tikzjax), but seem to be very limited.